# How to calculate sum based on one dimension's distinct members in MDX?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm relatively new to SSAS and MDX.
My SSAS cube has the following facts and dimensions with the columns as shown below

`FactAmount`: `amountHT`

`FactPayroll`: `payroll`

`DimMember`: `memberId`, `memberName`, ...

`DimTax`: `hierarchy taxCode => taxDetailCode`

`DimGeography`: `hierarchy country => area => district`

Here's an example of my data cube :

```
DimMember | DimTax | DimGeography | amountHT  | payroll
------------------------------------------------------
1         | FC     | AQUI         | 200 $     | 1000 $

1         | TA     | AQUI         | 150 $     | 1000 $

2         | FC     | PACA         | 750 $     | 2500 $

2         | FC     | PACA         | 800 $     | 2500 $

3         | FC     | AQUI         | 110 $     | 650 $
```

I want to create a calculated member showing payroll's sum per member.

For my example => 1000 + 2500 + 650

Comment: Is your SSAS multidimensional or tabular?

Comment: my SSAS multidimensional.

Comment: I don't understand the question: why are you adding 1000 + 2500 + 650 when these relate to `DimMember: {1, 1, 3}` ? You say `payroll's sum per member` but it seems to be summing over the members 1 and 3?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your first comment's question. I can try to explain that I want in SQL:
select sum(t.amountHT) as amountHT, sum(t.payroll) as payroll 
from ( 
select sum(amountHT) as amountHT, avg(payroll) as payroll from 'my_data' group by DimMember
) as t

About your second comment's link, this is the same post proposed in vercelli's answer. But many-to-many relationship doesn't work.

Comment: Is your Payroll factual table connected to DimTax or DimGeography?

Comment: Payroll and AmountHT are in the same factual table. This table is connected to DimTax and DimGeography.

Comment: What is the aggregation you setup for the measure payroll? Max?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is solved in this post
[SSAS Aggregation on Distinct ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032219/ssas-aggregation-on-distinct-id)

Comment: I have already tried this but it doesn't work if two different members have the same payroll.


With a fourth member who has a payroll of 1000 $, 
the sum must equal : 1000 + 2500 + 650 + 1000

Comment: Why is this comment marked as the answer?